# Sending a transaction with a value parameter to a contract method

Tags: contract-invocation, bad-jump

Here's a simple contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Test {
    uint public sum;
    function makeRequest(){
      sum += msg.value;
    }
}
```

Here's JS code:

```
function onLoad(){
    const web3 = window.web3;
    const address = "0x26c5267d77348d2748f075d884c75f1a6274149b";
    const abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"makeRequest","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"sum","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}];
    const contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);

    const txo = {
        from: "0x6Ca2f35Ff53c3764ADD78d52378bbFb41CbEef63",
        value: 10000000000000000
    };
    contract.makeRequest(txo, (error, result) => {});
}
```

Executing JS code results in failed transactions like this [one](https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x5fe216c239b0d2781fa36f732b223bafad878f38cc39b9baf226fbeab06cd42c).
Error:

> Bad jump destination

What am I missing?

Comment: Hello. I'm not really sure about it, but maybe you have to set up a gas value in `txo`, e.g `gas: '4700000'`

Comment: @frenchieisverige, just explicitly told MetaMask to use 1000000 gas and nothing changed -- tx's still fail.

Comment: Bad Jump destination reminds me how the EVM is working inside. It is just a set of instructions and also where to jump to the next one.
So maybe you do need the ByteCode of your smart contract, so the EVM knows where to jump.

The following code is in web3.js but maybe you'll get it too:
`var bytecode = 'yourByteCode';

//Contract Object parameters
var deployContractObject = {
    from: account,
    data: bytecode,
    gas: '4700000'
};
var sc = contract.new(deployContractObject, function(e, contract) {
console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address );
}
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
"payable":false
```

Try to change your contract (or its ABI) making this method payable.

Comment: yay, it works!!! I love you, good sir! Thank you for your time and knowledge!